# Manually crop image in wordpress with custom size

Tags: wordpress, image, crop

I want to make my image(thumbnail here) crop to a size as I want when use.

I search and tried the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` as told as below, and also other method.

```
$img_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);

$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src(, $image)[0];

echo $img[2];
```

But still cannot work as expect.

What's the most convenient way to do this? please help.

Comment: Not know Wordpress very well, but what happens with first parameter? `wp_get_attachment_image_src(, $image)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2.5 wordpress don't accept the second parameter `$size` of function `wp_get_attachment_image_src` to be array of integer size.

But we can add the size as we expect, using:

```
add_image_size('my-image-size-name', $w, $h, $crop);
```

But the image resize and cropping would be triggered after this call when image upload.

And when the image uploads after that, the specified size of image thumbnail will be generated. (So the images uploaded before this function call don't create thumbnail images).

And when we want to call this size of thumbnail, we call:

$img_id = get_post_thum

```
bnail_id($post->ID);

$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'my-image-size-name')[0];

echo $img[2];
```

That works.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the wp function:

```
$image= wp_get_attachment_image_src($img_id, 'thumbnail'); // medium, large, full

echo $image['src'];
```

you are obviously going to have to use wp sizes but you can obviously use css to resize as you want. For true cropping check out php image crop.